# Getting inside a monad wrapped in transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

This is a contrieved example using Reader Transformer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Char

conv ∷ Int → ReaderT Char Maybe String
conv n = do
   yn ← ask
   if yn == 'y'
      then return $ chr n : " with Yes"
      else lift Nothing

-- runReaderT (conv 98) 'y'      Just "b with Yes"
-- runReaderT (conv 98) '@'      Nothing

inspect ∷ ReaderT Char Maybe String → Bool
```

-- EDITED: as per suggestions, the correct type is monadic:

```
inspect ∷ ReaderT Char Maybe String → ReaderT Char Maybe Bool
```

`inspect` is supposed to check whether the value inside is Nothing. Can it be done, or I am having "design issues"?

Comment: You can't inspect the value without running the reader since the answer depends on the value in the environment.

Comment: Of course not.  I was implying "runReaderT inspect ..." somewhere along the lines.

Comment: what Lee means is that you want `inspect :: ReaderT Char Maybe String -> ReaderT Char Maybe Bool` - the signature you gave can basically only give back a constant (it could feed the `Reader` with it's own environment/`Char` etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ReaderT) is exactly

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
        -- a function that reads the environment^    |
        --                         and returns an m a^
```

For `ReaderT r Maybe a` it's a function that reads the environment and returns a `Maybe a`. You can make a function that  reads the environment and checks if the result is `Nothing` by composing this function with another function that checks whether the result is `Nothing`. To check whether a `Maybe a` is nothing, we can use [`isJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:isJust), and to pack the resulting `Bool` back into a `Maybe Bool` we'd use `return`.

```
inspect :: ReaderT r Maybe a -> ReaderT r Maybe Bool
inspect (ReaderT f) = ReaderT $ return . isJust . f
```

transformers provides a function, [`mapReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:mapReaderT) that lets us manipulate the computation inside a `ReaderT`

```
mapReaderT :: (m a -> n b) -> ReaderT r m a -> ReaderT r n b
mapReaderT f m = ReaderT $ f . runReaderT m
```

`mapReaderT` just composes the function provided as its first argument with the function inside the `ReaderT` (`runReaderT` unwraps the function inside a `ReaderT`). You can use `mapReaderT` to write `inspect` more elegantly.

```
inspect :: ReaderT r Maybe a -> ReaderT r Maybe Bool
inspect = mapReaderT (return . isJust)
```